# R: can I tell plm which variables to use the within transformation on?

Tags: r, plm

I have a dataset where I want to group countries on a broader level then per country. Still, the country is the id variable in my dataset. Example:

```
library(plm)
Data <- data.frame(iris)
Data$time <- c(rep(1951:2000,3))
Data$mygroup <- c(rep("a",100),rep("b",50))

test <- plm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length,data=Data, model="within", index=c("time","Species"))
summary(test)
```

Can I tell `plm` somehow, that I want the within transformation to happen over `mygroup` rather than `species`? If I use mygroup as the index, I run into trouble with duplicate years per id which I'm guessing bothers `plm` when trying to calculate individual specific constants etc.

```
test2 <- plm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length,data=Data, model="within", index=c("time","mygroup"))
```

I could simply build dummies based on `mygroup` and include them but the within transformation should be more efficient and also seems more elegant. I don't see an option for this in the `plm` help file though. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to sweep out additional effects in plm by the within tansformation (besides regular id and time dimension). As you suggested you can use dummies for `mygroup` to do that. If the number of groups is not very large, I do not see any drawbacks - just a minor "pollution" of the output.

Otherwise, if you want to sweep out additional effects by a within transformation you can use the package `lfe` for that. It is especially handy if you have a large number of additional effects you want to sweep out and/or if the number of groups is very large as you avoid pollution of our output and computation is faster for large data sets (`lfe` implements the within transformation in `C`).

By the way, you should swap `"time"` and `"Species"` in your example:

```
test <- plm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length,data=Data, model="within", index=c("Species", "time"))
```